# PHP - load a file depending on the name of the last directory in URL

Tags: php, if-statement

How can I load a PHP file depending on the name of the last directory in the URL

example 1 url: http://www.example.com/en/auto/
example 2 url: http://www.example.com/en/auto/mercedes/

If the last directory in the url is auto (as in first url example) then load file auto.php

if the last directory in the url is mercedes (as in second url example) then load file mercedes.php

Comment: Are you using the Apache web server? This is a task for URL rewriting (mod_rewrite, htaccess), not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from above solution you can try following:

```
$url = trim('http://www.example.com/en/auto', '/');
$loadUrl=substr($url, strrpos($url, '/')+1);
header("Location:".$loadUrl.".php");
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by *Michael Berkowski*, the `.htaccess` is the right way to do it, however, you could achieve a *(very)* hack version with something similar to this (**Note:** I have no idea how you intend to "load" the file and from where, so I am using `include()`):

```
<?php
    // Remove trailing forward slash
    $str    =   rtrim('http://www.example.com/test/is/best/',"/");
    // Simple match characters from back
    $exp    =   preg_match("!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$!",$str,$match);
    // $match[1] gives you: best
    if(isset($match[1])) {
            // $redirect gives you: best.php
            if(is_file($redirect = $match[1].".php")) {
                    // Include the best.php
                    include($redirect);
                }
        }
?>
```